# pythagoras theorem validation on C

Tags: c

What am I doing wrong here ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double pythagoras (double x, double y);
    int x[] = {3,3,1, -1, -1, 1, -3, 0, 6};
    int y[] = {4, -4, 1,1,-1,-1,0,4,9};
    {
        double z;
        for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(x)/sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            z = pythagoras(x[i],y[i]);
            z = sqrt(double pow(x,2) + double pow(y,2));
            printf("%3d, %3d, %9.5f\n" , x[i] ,y[i] , z);
        }
        printf("%3d, %3d, %9.5f\n" , 5,12,pythagoras(5,12) );
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a declaration of `pythagoras`, but no definition of it.

Comment: Usually function declarations are put at top level, not inside functions.

Comment: how van I can write the definition i have been struggling with this all day. I am new with coding

Comment: Google "c function definition tutorial".

Comment: You already asked this once.  What was wrong with the earlier comments/answers?

Comment: I still couldn't solve it :| this is really hard

Comment: _Side note:_ `sizeof(x)/sizeof(int)` is more idiomatic if it is: `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` The latter works even if you change the type of `x` (e.g. `int x[]` --> `long x[]`).

Comment: Don't call `pow(x,2)` when you can just do `x*x` instead.  The latter will be much faster, and probably more accurate as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your `pythagoras` function like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double pythagoras(int,int); //Function Declaration

int main(){
    int x[] = {3,3,1,-1,-1,1,-3,0,6};
    int y[] = {4,-4,1,1,-1,-1,0,4,9};
    double z;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(x)/sizeof(int); i++){
        z = pythagoras(x[i],y[i]); // Function Call
        printf("%3d, %3d, %9.5f\n", x[i], y[i], z);
    }
    printf("%3d, %3d, %9.5f\n", 5, 12, pythagoras(5,12)); //Function Call
    return 0;
}

//Function Definition
double pythagoras(int x, int y){
    return sqrt(pow(x,2) + pow(y,2));
}
```